# Не выводится число на assembler

Tags: ассемблер

Имеем задачу - Написать подпрограмму декремента числа меньшего 10.
Вывести результат на экран. Входное значение передавать
через глобальные переменные

имеем asm код, который не выбивает число

```
mov ah, 0x02
mov ax, 10
mov dl,0

dec word ax
mov dl,ax
add dl,'0'

mov dl, 0x02

int 0x21
```

помогите решить вопрос, пожалуйста укажите на недочёты.

Answer (score 1):

Так вам же нужно подпрограмму написать, а у вас программа без всяких подпрограмм. Ну да ладно, у вас тут и так ошибки:

1)

```
mov ah, 0x02
mov ax, 10
```

В регистр AH вы записали номер функции вывода MS-DOS 0x2, а следующей инструкцией вы перезаписали это значение на 0, т.к. переслали в регистр ax число 10, т.е. 0x000A. Младшая часть 0x0A попадает в AL, а старшая 0 - в AH. Регистры AH и AL являются старшей и младшей частями регистра AX - это всегда нужно помнить. Уже всё поломано.

2)

```
mov dl,ax
```

Здесь вообще не понятно, как что-то могло скомпиллироваться, т.к. это синтаксическая ошибка. Вы не можете переслать в 8-битный DL 16-битный AX. Вам надо либо так:

```
mov dx,ax
```

либо так:

```
mov dl,al
```

3. 

```
mov dl, 0x02
```

А это зачем?

4. Да и вообще, вам же подпрограмма нужна, причём принимающая число в какой-то глобальной переменной. Не знаю, какой там у вас транслятор, по-этому не могу предложить рабочий код. Могу только предоставить исправленный фрагмент, который вами приведен:

   ```
    mov ax, 10 ;поменяли местами
    mov ah, 0x02

    ;mov dl,0 это зачем?

    dec al
    mov dl,al
    add dl,'0'

    int 0x21
   ```

И да, раз входное число должно быть меньше 10 (и больше нуля, полагаю), то не мешало бы добавить проверок в код. Кстати, 10==10))

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это необходимо было сделать для nasm